# installing NEURON package for python on mac

Tags: mac, python

I have some problems with installing NEURON package.
first, the problem is that I can't import neuron in PyCharm and I get an error that "No module named 'neuron'".
also in terminal after installing XQuartz and command line tool and anaconda when I run "conda install mayavi" I get this error: "ImportError: No module named site"

can anyone help me please?

Comment: Do you have NEURON installed? Verify if it is installed by running `pip list`.

Comment: WHat is your $PATH and $CONDA_* environment variables? and in PyCharm what python environment have you set in Preferences for the project?

Comment: How did you install neuron?

Comment: I tried this tutorial: [https://www.neuron.yale.edu/ftp/neuron/nrn_mac_install.pdf]